# Скрипт раскрывает все подменю сразу

Tags: html, jquery

Написал скрипт, который должен по клику на пункт меню открывать подменю с остальными ссылками. Но почему-то скрипт открывает подменю всех пунктов сразу, а мне нужно открывать именно соседний блок с подменю. Где у меня ошибка?

```
$(function() { // функция включения/отключения показа мобильного меню
    var touch = $('li .menu-link');
    var menu = $('li .menu-link ~ .dropdown-list');

    $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 992 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">Билеты</a>
    <div class="dropdown-list">
        <div class="menu-items">
            <a href="#"><i style="color: #ff6f00;" class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Спецпредложения</a>
            <a href="#"><i style="color: #ffb300;" class="material-icons">star_rate</i>Популярные рейсы</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если опираться именно на Ваш пример, то чуточку подправить поиск menu.
Вы ищите все меню, а нужно конкретно для этой li-шки с этой ссылкой.

```js
$(function() { // функция включения/отключения показа мобильного меню
    var touch = $('li .menu-link');

    $(touch).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      
        var menu = $(this).closest('li').find('.dropdown-list');
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        var menu = $('li .menu-link ~ .dropdown-list');
        if(w > 992 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-list {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">Билеты</a>
    <div class="dropdown-list">
        <div class="menu-items">
            <a href="#"><i style="color: #ff6f00;" class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Спецпредложения</a>
            <a href="#"><i style="color: #ffb300;" class="material-icons">star_rate</i>Популярные рейсы</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menu-link">Билеты</a>
    <div class="dropdown-list">
        <div class="menu-items">
            <a href="#"><i style="color: #ff6f00;" class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Спецпредложения</a>
            <a href="#"><i style="color: #ffb300;" class="material-icons">star_rate</i>Популярные рейсы</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Да, это сработало. Но анимация почему-то подтормаживает. Я гуглил, и думал, что проблема связана с padding или margin-отступами. Убрал всё, задал фиксированную высоту, и всё равно анимация вначале и в конце "прыгает".